# REST Service - poor performance issue

Tags: xpages

I'm using the REST Service control in an XPage (XAgent) and I experience slow performance..

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:restService id="byNameFirst" pathInfo="Read">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewItemFileService var="entry" defaultColumns="true"
                count="3000">
                <xe:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.getUrl().getParameter("view")}]]></xe:this.viewName>
            </xe:viewItemFileService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
</xp:view>
```

The XAgent is called using :
server/dbpath/xRestService.xsp/Read?view=lookupREST

Server is Domino 8.5.3 with UP1
The view (lookupREST) is FTIndexed and has 15 non-computed columns.
I've experimented with setting the count (number of returned rows).

- Setting count to 10, data is returned in 60ms (average from 20 requests)
- Setting count to 100, data is returned in 2s (average from 20 requests) (!)
- Setting count to 1000, data is returned in 2s (average from 20 requests)
- Setting count to 3000, data is returned in 5.5s (average from 20 requests) (!)

Result: returning 10 is fast, 100 is very slow, 1000 is slow, 3000 is very slow..

I was hoping it was faster. Should I expect faster response than this ?
I've testet the overall server http performance with other xpages, forms, pages etc, and I find it good.

I've also tested with using the viewJsonService. I find it slower. Using 3000 as count averages to about 10 seconds.

So, questions is should I expect faster response times than this ? What could be possible cause(s) for this slow performance ?
Or is this performing as expected ?

Any information / tips would be greatly appreciated Smile

Regards,
Petter Kjeilen

Comment: Petter - have you timed the speed to appear on the page - or the speed of response from the server? Using Firebug or Chrome dev tools you can see the response time and the download time - how do they correlate? Knowing that can help identify the problem

Comment: Could you also try using Domino Data Service http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Data+Service#action=openDocument&res_title=Viewfolder_entries_GET_dds10&content=pdcontent . It may be faster if you just want to get JSON output out of a view.

Comment: @MarkyRoden - yes, this has been tested using firebug. Waiting time average to about 5.5 seconds. (using 3000 as count) Connecting about 30ms and Receiving to about 280ms.

Comment: @EgorMargineanu - I've now tested using Domino Data Service. unfortunately it's slower. I get 3000 documents returned in about 9-10 seconds (average of 20 attempts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare that with your server's base line first. Since you are using views you can use

```
http://yourserver/yourdb.nsf/viewName?ReadViewEntries&OutputFormat=JSON&Count=1000
```

This gives you the raw server performance (you need to tweak server settings to get more than a 1000 at a time). If the results are not too different then watch your server I/O (DiskQueue) to identify the bottleneck

Comment: @Stephan - Yes, I've tried your approach as well and it's quicker. 3000 documents are returned in 3 seconds (about half the time..)
But, I also need the ability to sort and filter on the server side..
Just for getting the data it's a good solution.

Comment: Seems like Notes.jar is the bottleneck -> http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/31.03.2010220936KLERN4.htm

Comment: Sort is available, as is filtering to some extend. Check the URL command doku

Comment: Yes, ResortAscending=column number or ResortDecending=column number can be used for sorting. Filtering is more tricky thought..